# MDX query dynamic where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, mdx

```
SELECT NON EMPTY  {  [Measures].[Total  Value],[Measures].[Value less than 30], 
[Measures].[Value less than 60],[Measures].[Value less than 90],[Measures].[Value less than 150],
[Measures].[Value less than 180],[Measures].[Value less than 365],[Measures].[Value more than 365]}   
DIMENSION PROPERTIES CHILDREN_CARDINALITY,  PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS,   
NON EMPTY  {[Combined].[Drill Down Path 4].[Supplier Name].ALLMEMBERS }   
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS FROM [InventoryAge]  
WHERE ( [Calendar].[Report Days].[All Members].&[All].&[WantInReport].&[2].&[20141031] )
```

for the where clause I want to get the last element of my calender dimension. The calender dimension is as follows

[image]

What is the best way to achieve this

Comment: In `[Calendar].[Report Days].[All Members].&[All].&[WantInReport].&[2].&[20141031]` I guess .&[2]. refers to `[Last Days]` . What's the content of this item, could you expand it in your screenshot?

Comment: I have updated the screen shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
WHERE ( [Calendar].[Report Days].[All Members].[All].[WantInReport].[Last Days].LastChild )
```

You should be able to use the name of your members (but with removing & in front of them), that's why `.&[WantInReport].` become `.&[WantInReport].`.

I'd rather use `.[Last Days].` than `.&[2].`, easier to understand when you look later at the query.

Finally using `.LastChild` gives you last item of your selected branch.